# RoR: nested namespace routes, undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the admin section of a new rails app and i'm trying to setup some routes to do things "properly". I have the following controller:

```
class Admin::BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @blogs = Blog.find(:all)
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :blogs
end
```

in views/admin/blogs/index.html.erb:

```
<% for blog in @blogs %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_blog(blog), :method => :delete
<% end %>
```

i have verified that the routes exist:

```
admin_blogs GET /admin/blogs {:action => "index", :controller=>"admin/blogs"}
admin_blog  GET /admin/blogs/:id {:action => "show", :controller => "admin/blogs"}
....
```

but when i try to view http://localhost:3000/admin/blogs i get this error:

```
undefined method 'admin_blog' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb7213da8>
```

where am i going wrong and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Delete link should end in _path:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_blog_path(blog), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using rails 2.0.x so the way you generate a route is
__path

```
admin_blog_path(blog)
```

and if you are riding a previous version I think it's just

```
blog_path(blog)
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note:
I also see that your controller is defined like this:

```
class Admin::BlogsController < ApplicationController
```

shouldn't it be like this?

```
class Admin::BlogsController < Admin::ApplicationController
```